# I am not able to get a list of id from the below json with the help of RestAssured JsonPath

Tags: java, rest-assured, jsonpath, rest-assured-jsonpath

I am not able to get a list of id from the below json with the help of RestAssured JsonPath.

```
{
    "Test": [
        {
            "id": "657"
        },
        {
            "id": "2711"
        }
    ],
    "Test2": [
        {
            "id": "657"
        },
        {
            "id": "711"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: The JSON is invalid. Property names (`"id"`) in JavaScript objects `{}`have to be unique. Entor your JSON on https://jsonlint.com/. It will show the error _SyntaxError: Duplicate key 'id' on line 4_. 
This would be valid: ```{
 "Test": [{
   "id": "21657"
  },
  {
   "id": "21658"
  }
 ],
 "Test2": [{
   "id": "216571"
  },
  {
   "id": "216581"
  }
 ]
}```

Comment: OK, still not able? You should provide more information. What are you trying to do? What is you JsonPath query? Do you get an error message?

Comment: what do you mean that you are unable to? a simple `$..id` gives me the list of id's.